# Connecting PC to TV screen; Both go black

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, tv

My PC is currently connected to a 21" Samsung Monitor, and I wanted to connect it to a Samsung 4K TV as well. The PC is connected to the monitor using a DVI cable, and the TV using a DVI - HDMI adapter.

The Monitor is connected fine, but as soon as I connect the TV, both go black, and the Monitor is flashing the ANALOG - HDMI Screen. This is the same if I set the PC to 'Extend' or 'Duplicate'. When I change it to the TV only, the screen shows 'Resolution not supported, please change the resolution on your external device'.

The PC is using an ATI RADEON 4800 HD video card.

Is the problem due to the old video card, or is it a different problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screen is telling you the most vital piece of information. 
The 4K TV has a much larger resolution (3840 x 2160) than your graphics card can support.

The ATI Radeon HD 4800 has an [R700 series chipset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_4000_series#Radeon_Feature_Matrix) architecture, specifically the RV770 GPU for this card. These GPUs have a maximum resolution output of 2560 x 1600.

Comment: So getting a new graphics card is the only solution?

Comment: Unless the TV has settings (or another input) that will allow it to accept a resolution your video card can produce, it's likely the only solutions are to either replace the video card or replace the television, yes.